Serial killer keeps women captive with a friend
What's this movie? It's about a man (I think he's a bit fat) and he has a mentally challenged partner in crime. In one scene the serial killer and his friend (I think his name is Newt or something) are sitting on either side of a woman in a bathtub and they mutilate her. 
Additional details:

It's in English and I think it's set in America.
I think it was made in 2010 - 2014. 
Also the guy keeps several women captive and there's some sort of pattern behind the women he chooses, like they're all linked in some way. 


It could be but I THINK the title was limited to one word. It's so hard to say anything specific cuz I watched it ages ago

This is very likely A Darker Reality from 2008 with    Daniel Baldwin, which was based on an earlier film with a similar title. From an online review:

The Ghost [...] is a serial killer, responsible so far for the disappearances of eighty-five women [...] Some of them are still alive in, presumably, the basement of the house he shares with his [chubby] mentally challenged, equally sadistic brother Newt (Man Overboard‘s Arthur Bullock, one of the actors reprising his role from Dark Reality).

They both abuse some of the women in a bathtub. Here's the trailer (Warning: Graphic):




That's it, A Darker Reality. Thanks so much!

@AllTehGames No problem! Don't forget to approve the answer by clicking on the check mark.
